# How add a * after required fields in django modelform?

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a django modelform that some of it's fields are required. i'm using `{{ form.as_p }}` and i'm not accessing the fields individually.

so how can i add a star (*) for that required fields in the form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will not be accessing the fields individually (such as using {{ form.as_p }}), then you can add a property to your ModelForm:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

That will define all fields that are required as having the 'required' class

Then you can add the asterisk using CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .required:after { content: '*'; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change the label

```
class Form(ModelForm):
    model = <model>
    labels = {
        "<field_name>": "<label>*",
    }
```

or you can set an id for the field using widgets and set a label for that id:

```
class Form(ModelForm):
    model = <model>
    widgets = {
        "<field_name>": "<widget_obj>(attrs={"id": "<id>"})*",
    }
```